# How to get the summary of (mysql_fetch_array)

Tags: php, mysql

is that possible to output the summary of INT variables in (mysql_fetch_array)?

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT numbers FROM table ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 3");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['number'] . "<br/>";
}
```

the output would be like this:

> 23
> 37
> 31

The question is can i output the sumarry of this three results in the same while loop? Which it's "91".

Comment: what's the point in selecting sum of 3 random rows?

Comment: @your common sense - - there are plenty of reasons you might.  It could be some sort of game, it might be creating some sort of puzzle, and other reasons I haven't thought of yet :P

Comment: It is a shame people don't give a little slack to users whose primary language might not be English.  Go ahead @kirilloid and ask the same question in Mandarin and see how your intent might be misinterpreted.

Comment: @Steve I had similar situation with German. Yes, ppl told me my German is awful and I knew it. Anyway, it is strange to see a question: "How to sum numbers".

Comment: @MichalPlško you said, comment shouldn't be answered and wrote an answer by yourself. BTW: I deleted my comment.

Comment: @Steve I asked the OP, not you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why  in the same loop?  Why not just do something like this?

```
        //initialise your variable
        $total = 0;
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT numbers FROM table ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 3");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['number'] . "<br/>";
        //running total
        $total = $total + $row['number'];
    }
        //output it
        echo "total = " . $total;
```

Answer (score 1):

What a disaster. Everyone here has suggested `ORDER BY RAND()` and use of `mysql_*`. It's actually scary level of ignorance.

**`ORDER BY RAND()` is extremely slow.** The complexity of `ORDER BY RAND()` is `N * log2(N)`. Which means, that selecting entry from 1000 row table, will take ~3000 time longer then from 10 row table.

If you want to learn, **how** to select items at random from a table **[read this article](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/)**. If you just want the solution for your problem: skip to the "Multiple Rows at once" section ( almost at the bottom ).

As for the rest of it: **stop using `mysql_*` API to access MySQL database.** It is more then 10 years old, and not only it isn't maintained anymore, but also the process of deprecation [has begun](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) already.

You code should have looked like (if using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) instead of [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli), which is other alternative for accessing MySQL in year 2012):

```
$statement = $pdo->query(' ... your query here ... ');
if ( $statement->execute() )
{
    $data = $statement->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) );
    foreach( $data as $item )
    {
        $total += $item['numbers'];
    }
}
```

P.S. if you actually want to learn something about SQL, you definitely should read [SQL Antipatterns](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns), or at least read carefully through the [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back) made by the author.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. You could do it for example like this:

```
$summary = 0;
$result=mysql_query("SELECT numbers FROM table ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 3");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $summary = $summary + $row['number'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name LIMIT 3
```

It should give the same result.

Comment: Yes, but if you also wanted to output your individual results it means making a second call to the database.